# Xcode 11.1 Only Takes Square Photos - Need 4:3

Tags: xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, swiftui

[image: square only]

I'm using the camera to capture images for an app. Once I touch the photo button, I am
only able to save the photo in a square format. I want to preserve the 4:3 format for
older cameras and eventually allow the user to choose 16:9 if desired. I have not been
able to find any code to programmatically chose aspect ratio. I only get square. I even
tried locking the Camera Mode in Camera Settings on the device. Thankfully, that
didn't work.

It is a SwiftUI app. In the CameraViewController below, if I remove the allowsEditing
option, the picker freezes - neither the Use Photo, nor Retake buttons function. The
app does not crash, just the view is frozen. I am able to swipe down the view to
dismiss and continue using the app.

I call the PhotoCaptureView below from a button in what would be the detail view of
a master/detail equivalent.

PhotoCaptureView:

```
import SwiftUI
struct PhotoCaptureView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var cameraSettings: CameraSettings
    @Binding var photos: [UIImage]

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            CameraViewController(photos: $photos)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

And the model view CameraViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import MobileCoreServices
import AVFoundation

struct CameraViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @EnvironmentObject var cameraSettings: CameraSettings
    @Binding var photos: [UIImage]

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewContyroller: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
        //no code here
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraViewController>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let vc = UIImagePickerController()
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera) {
            vc.sourceType = .camera
            vc.allowsEditing = true
            vc.delegate = context.coordinator
            return vc
        }
        return UIImagePickerController()
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        var parent: CameraViewController
        init(_ imagePickerController: CameraViewController) {
            self.parent = imagePickerController
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
                print("no image found")
                return
            }
            print("Image taken successfully, with size \(image.size)")
            parent.photos.append(image)
            picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
                print("in dismiss after successful picture")
            }
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
                print("in did cancel")
            }
        }

        private func pickerController(_ controller: UIImagePickerController, didSelect image: UIImage?) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The CameraSettings are just Bools to determine whether to present the camera option.

```
class CameraSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isAuthorized: Bool = false
    @Published var isCameraAvailable: Bool = false
}
```

Xcode 11.1 (11A1027) I am using an iPhone X iOS 13.1.2

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `SwiftUI`? Are you trying to say that your `UIKit` code works perfectly fine in a storyboard app? To be honest, I'm not even sure this is an Xcode 11.1 or iOS 13.1.2 question. My code works fine. EDIT: My apps are Xcode, including 11.2 beta, use UIImagePickerController, and are storyboard apps. I've never tried this in SwiftUI (just picking selected images in a representable), so that *may* be your issue. But my question stands - does your code work in a storyboard app?

Comment: I have used basically the same code in a number of Swift apps for several years. It works very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The info setting of didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo needs to specify "originalImage" to avoid the square only picture. Even with the edited version, however, it seems you can only move the image around - not change the aspect.

change the info line above to:
     guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {

Then set:
     vc.allowsEditing = false

Importantly the documentation tells me that: "The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only."